# Extract data from two dictionaries embedded in one and combine data

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have to import data in a certain way where I have two dictionaries (I think) embedded in each other. The dictionary looks something like this:

```
rawData = {'Force': {'X': [3,4,5], 'Y': [6,1,8], 'Z': [-9,43,52]}, 'Moment': {'X': [-35,44,5], 'Y': [31,44,55], 'Z': [-13,34,535]}}
```

I would like to create a dictionary with only one layer, and that combines the embedded keys of both dictionaries so that it looks like this:

```
data = {'ForceX': [3,4,5], 'ForceY': [6,1,8], 'ForceZ':  [-9,43,52], 'MomentX': [-35,44,5], 'MomentY': [31,44,55], 'MomentZ': [-13,34,535]}
```

Is there a way to pull the data out of the embedded dictionary, and merge the keys?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension with a nested loop.

```
{k1 + k2 : v2 for k1, v1 in rawData.items() for k2, v2 in v1.items()}

{'ForceX': [3, 4, 5],
 'ForceY': [6, 1, 8],
 'ForceZ': [-9, 43, 52],
 'MomentX': [-35, 44, 5],
 'MomentY': [31, 44, 55],
 'MomentZ': [-13, 34, 535]}
```